# Is there a version of the Chromium browser that will run on Ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy)

Tags: chromium, 8.04

Looking for a version of the Chromium-browser that will run on Ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy).

There must be one since I'm using Google Chrome 12.0.742.60 beta on that machine now but I've been unable to locate any. The ppa.launchpad.net directories for hardy are empty.

I don't think I want to fight with library compatibilities trying to compile from source given how out-of-date it would be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromium was not in the official repositories during 8.04. 8.10 was the first. Next to that Google Chrome 12.0.742.60 beta is not Chromium. Google chrome is the actual version Google released. But even Chrome was released for 8.10+ only.

You could check synaptic for the package. Maybe it gives a hint to where you got it from. 
But most likely you installed it from source.

You can find a september 2008 release of chromium here: http://media.codeweavers.com/pub/crossover/chromium/ But this is based of of Lucid, not Hardy.

Other option would be to try and install [Google Chrome from their website](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/?hl=nl&brand=CHMB&utm_campaign=nl&utm_source=nl-ha-emea-nl-sk&utm_medium=ha) It is more than likely to complain if your system is too old for it but it would not surprise me if you got this up and running even on 8.04. Chromium from the latest release might be a stretch.

Comment: I've found a lot of things that only work on 10.04 (Lucid) and above and have pretty much given up trying make them work on 8.04 (Hardy). Been scared to upgrade the Hardy machine to Lucid as it's sort of my master server since it's got a big hard drive. Hardy has proven to be rock solid reliable whereas it's taken a lot of fiddling to the Lucid machine in shape.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a  PPA that has the latest stable Chromium Browser **ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium** I found it at webupd8 [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/new-chromium-stable-and-development.html)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

It may be time for you to bite the bullet and upgrade though, as that version of Ubuntu hasn't been supported for quite a while.